Node and Yarn Dependency Checksum Error on macOS due to packageManager Field Addition
I'm working on a project with the following setup:

Node v20.15.0
Yarn v4.2.2
Corepack enabled

I have two packages in the dependencies section of my package.json:
"dependencies": {
  "first-package": "git+ssh://git@git.example.com:group/first-package.git#v2.4.0",
  "second-package": "git+ssh://git@git.example.com:group/second-package.git#v3.0.1"
}

During the installation of the project on macOS, I encounter checksum errors for these two packages. The error messages are as follows:
➤ YN0018: │ first-package@git+ssh://git@git.example.com:group/first-package.git#commit=commit-hash: The remote archive doesn't match the expected checksum
➤ YN0018: │ second-package@git+ssh://git@git.example.com:group/second-package.git#commit=commit-hash: The remote archive doesn't match the expected checksum

Interestingly, there are no errors on Linux and Windows installations.
Upon investigating the packages within the node_modules folder, we discovered that the installation on macOS adds a packageManager field to the package.json of the packages downloaded from the git server. It seems this alteration is causing the checksum mismatch.
I found and reviewed these GitHub issues:
Yarn Issue #2399
Yarn Issue #4917
Unfortunately, they did not provide a solution to my problem.
We also tried adding the following to package.json:
"dependenciesMeta": {
  "first-package": { "built": false },
  "second-package": { "built": false }
}

However, this did not resolve the issue either.
How can I prevent the addition of the packageManager field to my git packages on macOS to ensure checksum consistency?

The problem was with corepack.
I just disabled corepack, then I had to install yarn, removed node_modules, cleared yarn cache and then everything worked fine.
